# KeyError when initializing ResNet using Dlib in python

Tags: python, dlib, resnet, deepface

I want to use DeepFace DlibResNet but it gives error.
I have already installed dlib 19.24.0 and deepface 0.0.79.
My python version is 3.10.5 and I use Jupiyter Lab.

```
import dlib
from deepface import DeepFace
from deepface.basemodels.DlibResNet import DlibResNet
dlib_model = DlibResNet()
```

---

```
dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat is going to be downloaded
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 17
      3 from deepface.basemodels.DlibResNet import DlibResNet          
   (...)
---> 17 dlib_model = DlibResNet()

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\deepface\basemodels\DlibResNet.py:32, in DlibResNet.__init__(self)
     30 url = f"http://dlib.net/files/{file_name}"
     31 output = f"{home}/.deepface/weights/{file_name}"
---> 32 gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
     34 zipfile = bz2.BZ2File(output)
     35 data = zipfile.read()

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\gdown\download.py:178, in download(url, output, quiet, proxy, speed, use_cookies, verify, id, fuzzy, resume, format)
    173     url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id={id}".format(
    174         id=gdrive_file_id
    175     )
    176     continue
--> 178 if res.headers["Content-Type"].startswith("text/html"):
    179     m = re.search("<title>(.+)</title>", res.text)
    180     if m and m.groups()[0].endswith(" - Google Docs"):

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\structures.py:52, in CaseInsensitiveDict.__getitem__(self, key)
     51 def __getitem__(self, key):
---> 52     return self._store[key.lower()][1]

KeyError: 'content-type'
```

What is the provlem? What should I do?

Comment: Seems like it's failing to download the model weights. Can you check if you have this file 'dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat.bz2' under the directory '/deepface/weights/'?

Comment: @Raktim I don't know why it fails to download the weights file. I tested gdown using another file and it works. By the way I finally downloaded the weights using IDM.

Comment: Did it work after downloading the weights? I was able to run your snippet in colab with no issues.

Comment: @Raktim Yes. It worked after manually downloading the weights.

Comment: Most probably you cannot download it because of a proxy or firewall. Target file is available.

Answer (score 3):

As a work around, from the cmd line run the following:

```
   python
   from deepface.commons import functions
   functions.get_deepface_home()
```

from this you'll get the {home} directory where deepface stores the weights, so you want to download the weights you require directly from dlib (http://dlib.net/files/) and then place them uncompressed in the directory {home}/.deepface/weights/{file_name}